# Input name attribute not changed

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to change my specific input field name attribute. I am trying with this code but not changed name.

My code successfully can track row number and specific input value. but cant change name.

my code is here

```
 var $table = this;
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $table.find('tr').click( function(){
         var tbl_row=$(this).index()+1;
         var column_name='total' + tbl_row;
         $($(this).find('td:eq(5)')).attr('name', column_name);
        });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting the value that you expect with `column_name` before try to make it the value of the name attribute?

Comment: Please post your HTML markup

Comment: It is always better to provide a Fiddle link in cases specific like this. Use https://jsfiddle.net/ , save your program and then share it

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth using the onsite editor is preferred to linking to an off site resource.  Ctrl+M or some have said click `<>` where ever that is.

Comment: Side note, `$($(this).find('td:eq(5)'))`, the secondary outer wrapping is unnecessary.  It's already a jQuery object.